# ASP.NET Core 1 EF - migrations update to latest

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.0

I have two migrations in my ASP.NET Core 1 MVC Project as follows:

[image: Migration VS2015]

The V1 migration is the initial migration with 1 table, Restaurants.

I added the v2 migration just now, which is after I added Asp.NET Identity to my project, and want to update my DB to this latest migration, but I am getting an error that the table already exists.

[image: dnx commands]

The Restaurant table does exist, but I thought that it would just do a drop-create and add the new tables as well. None of the new tables exist. I used the following commands to create:
**dnx ef migrations add v2** 
and then to update: **dnx ef database update**, i even tried specifying v2 but it keeps trying to migrate the initial version only.

[image: with migrations specified]

How do I get the second migration to update my existing Database?

UPDATE: i added a third migration, deleted the database and reran the update migrations command - this time only V1 and V2 ran, V3 did not. what gives?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't know the first migration was applied. Easiest thing would probably be to comment out the Up() code for the existing objects since it looks like you are doing a tutorial.

Comment: I guess I can Comment out the 'Restaurants' code, but any idea how to not do that? Just for future reference?

Comment: This is EF 6? Not sure why it didn't apply the first migration. You could check the table __MigrationHistory in your database and see if there are records in there - that's what EF checks to see what's been applied. You could also generate a script to see what EF is trying to do.

Comment: This is EF7, or EF1 ...whatever you want to call ASP.NET Core. The MigrationsHistory table only had the V1 info in there. Somewhere, one of the wires is not connected and im trying to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: Try to look in the underlying mapping of the database in the migration. Sometimes the mapping is not generated correctly or you have made some changes and because of that the mapping can be faulty

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "dbo.__MigrationHistory" table if it exists there in your database.
If it is not there, just delete your existing migrations. Add new migration and then update the database. It will create and sync your database with model.

if your are deleting the database then you also delete all existing migrations. And add new migration. You are still facing same issue then open your migration class and search for table "Restaurant".
Try to figure out:

- it is added twice or not
- it is added only once, comment out this and re-run update database command to see the next error.